# how to run the squish qt test suit from the python script

Tags: python, squish

when trying to run a testsuit from the python script the report generated by squish is always showing RuntimeError: Could not connect to Squish server at host 127.0.0.1, port 4322: Connection refused.
for all test cases.

'''  if os.path.exists(folder_path):
test_suite_names = [current_working_directory+"\test_suits\"+item for item in os.listdir(folder_path)]

commands = [
[squishrunner_path,
"--testsuite", test_suite_path,
"--testcase", "tst_master",  # Specify the test case name
"--reportgen", f"html,{report_filename}"]
for test_suite_path in test_suite_names
]

## Run all commands at once

for command in commands:
try:
subprocess.check_call(command)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
print(f"Error running squishrunner: {e}")'''

Comment: full code written  for above problem """""""
commands = [
    [squishrunner_path,
    "--testsuite", test_suite_path,
    "--testcase", "tst_master",  # Specify the test case name
    "--reportgen", f"html,{report_filename}"]
    for test_suite_path in test_suite_names
]

# Run all commands at once
for command in commands:
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(command)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running squishrunner: {e}")   """"""""""""     how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Get the command running in a shell first. When that works, take one step forward.

Answer (score 0):

did you actually run squish server beforehand?

When you run Squish runner by itself it wont start Squish server.

Just call your server in /squish_installation_folder/bin/squishserver and let it run as long as you need it to.